# How to determine the temp path of the nuget library after deploying

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, .net-core, openhtmltopdf

In my .net core web API , I'm using [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf/) nuget package for rendering HTML documents to PDF format. The implementation working fine locally but not in the server production K8 environment. I'm getting following message from the logs.

**`Permission denied`**

I did several workaround and was able to find out, a lib called `OpenHtmltoPdf` uses `Path.GetTempPath()` and `Guid.NewGuid()` to create a temp file. seems above permission denied error occurs when it trying to access that temp path. this is code snippet from the `OpenHtmltoPdf` lib.  [OpenHtmlToPdf git repo](https://github.com/vilppu/OpenHtmlToPdf)

```
//inside TemporaryPdf class
public static string TemporaryFilePath() 
{
  return Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "OpenHtmlToPdf", TemporaryPdf.TemporaryFilename());
}

private static string TemporaryFilename()
{
  return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".pdf";
}
```

I just added following line to my application to determine the temp path and its returns `File Path is: /tmp/`.

```
Console.WriteLine("File path is:" + Path.GetTempPath());
```

But in the Kubernetes pods have `rwx` permissions for `/tmp/` folder for the all users.

[image]

**My problem is, after deploying the API, do the NuGet packages use a separate temp path? So how exactly identify it?**

Comment: how about trying `File.Create(TemporaryPdf.TemporaryFilePath())`, do determine it is really this line of code causing issue?

Comment: For Path.GetTempPath() - "The path specified by the TMPDIR environment variable. If the path is not specified in the TMPDIR environment variable, the default path /tmp/ is used." . Try to set another "tmp" path by overwriting the environment variable.

Comment: @LeiYang I think you mean, add `Console.WriteLine("File path is " + Path.GetTempPath())` for the library? yeah I tried that too. but I couldn't determine.

Comment: no. i mean you write code to create the file, of course printing the path is also useful.

Comment: NuGet packages don't exist after compilation, nor do they affect the deployment environment. Since you want a temporary filename use [Path.GetTempFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=net-6.0) and don't bother about the name or extension. You can specify a different name when sending the file to the caller or copying it to its final location.

Comment: Are you looking at the host or pod tmp folder?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos pod `tmp` folder

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No actually I don't required TempFileName. just need to know the which folder uses by `openhtmltopdf` lib . the above code snippet from the  `openhtmltopdf` lib.

Comment: Did you already check what TemporaryFilePath returns to be sure the path is what you are expecting and writeable?

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi NuGet on the build machine doesn't affect the deployed machines. Try checking that path's permissions. You can use the `Mono.Posix` package and the [UnixDirectoryInfo](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix/UnixDirectoryInfo.cs) class to find the actual permissions of that path.